# Maven works in Command Prompt, but not in Power Shell

Tags: java, powershell, maven

I am very new to Maven and initial stages where i am exploring how to create a java EE project that i can host in a server. Maintain it through Maven.
First question is asked is how do i create the same structure of a java project that is created by Eclipse when i create a new Maven project in command line in Power Shell?

My findings -

[Please see the image snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUajM.png)

I understand that once we have a project crated. If you want to add modify how your project should build, we can modify that, or we can add new dependencies or many other things from the POM.xml.
But initially atleast it should create the structure of the maven project with a minimal pom.xml right ?

I used the command `mvn archetype:generate ...`. In the Command Prompt the project was created correctly. But I need Maven work in the Power Shell, and this produces an error:

```
The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
 in this directory ...
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

See tutorial. It is pretty good:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

To create a project structure:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false
```

For PowerShell, use quotes for `-D`, as follows:

```
mvn -B archetype:generate "-DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes" "-DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.
actually it is an issue when i try it in Powershell.
the same just worked in CMD